# StackOverflowException inside SimpleInjector in MVC WebApi project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, stack-overflow, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

We are building a website with UI and API, both hosted within single ASP.NET MVC project ("usual" MVC + MVC WebApi under one hood). We are using SimpleInjector (the latest version, 2.8 as of now) for dependency injection. We have single composition root class to construct containers for both UI and API parts.

Since recently (noticed a couple of weeks ago) we are receiving connection reset errors (`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`) when we try accessing any API method in QA. The same code in UAT works just fine.

Locally, the same code errors out with `StackOverflowException` if run under IIS, but works fine under IIS Express and under IIS if we run it with debugger attached.

Our current code gives the following stack trace when we attach to iis worker process after the exception occurs:

```
    SimpleInjector.Compiled!DynamicInstanceProducer3.GetInstance(object[] constants)
    SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.CompilationHelpers.CompileInDynamicAssemblyAsClosure<System.__Canon>.AnonymousMethod__1a()
    SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
    SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(System.Type serviceType)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Type controllerType, out System.Func<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController> activator)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, System.Type controllerType)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync()
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync>(ref System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync stateMachine)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync()
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync>(ref System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync stateMachine)
    System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore()
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore>(ref System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore stateMachine)
    System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> taskFunc, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)
    [AppDomain Transition]
```

I.e., looks like nothing bad happens inside our code.

When we take some old code (one that is currently in production, for instance, and is working fine), we also have `StackOverflowException`, but in static constructor of our EntityFramework DB context (code first) on line

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContextType, Configuration>());
```

Funny thing is that it no longer suggests to attach to the process with old code, so I cannot provide the stack trace - I will update the question, if I manage to grab it.

Note that usual MVC works normally still (while using the same Composition Root class with slight natural differences for WebApi and MVC creation modes).

I can provide further code snippets, if it is reasonable, but the project is quite big, so I am not sure small snippets will help here.

Any ideas what this might be? Can it be because of the number of dependencies?

**UPDATE:** The issue does not appear after in one of the services which depends on four other services I removed the dependencies from the constructor, injected the container there, and resolved the dependencies manually in the constructor. I.e., it was:

```
public MyDependentService(IDependency1 dependency1, IDependency2 dependency2, IDependency3 dependency3, IDependency4 dependency4)
{
    this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    this.dependency2 = dependency2;
    this.dependency3 = dependency3;
    this.dependency4 = dependency4;
}
```

and it became

```
public MyDependentService(Container container)
{
    this.dependency1 = container.GetInstance<IDependency1>();
    this.dependency2 = container.GetInstance<IDependency2>();
    this.dependency3 = container.GetInstance<IDependency3>();
    this.dependency4 = container.GetInstance<IDependency4>();
}
```

So now everything works, but of course this is not the right way to deal with dependencies. This is actually not IoC anymore. What's going on?

Comment: The number of dependencies in your registration can't cause a stackoverflow and Simple Injector will typically detect cyclic dependency graphs (to prevent stackoverflow exceptions from happening).

Comment: @Steven, that's what I rely on, and have indeed seen cyclic dependency exceptions a few times already, when there actually were cyclic dependencies in the code. Naturally, these exceptions appeared independently from the environment (IIS, IIS express, with or without debugger attached, etc.)

Comment: @Steven please take a look at the update. weird, is not it? I  think the number of dependencies can be the key here. What are generally causes for StackOverflow? The obvious one is too deep recursion, which would be noticeable in stacktrace (unless something inside SimpleInjector.Compiled!DynamicInstanceProducer3.GetInstance(object[] constants) is hidden). What else? I may be not strong enough in internals, but can it be because GetInstance receives an array of objects which can be huge and thus occupy too much space in the stack? Does this array size correlate with the number of dependencies?

Comment: Does `var result = Analyzer.Analyze(container)` trigger the exception?

Comment: You might have encountered a bug in Simple Injector. Is it possible for you to come up with a small example that reproduces the problem. It's best to create a Github issue for this, because SO isn't really suited for this.

Comment: @qujck We have a unit test that calls container.Verify(); and analyzes the result. Is not it the same? Verify gives no errors.

Comment: @Steven I'd love to reproduce it with small amount of code, but not sure I can. I will try. I will raise a bug anyway - hopefully, you'll be able to analyze the symptoms I described and the code to find something there (if the bug is there indeed).

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich `Verify` is almost the same but the exception is triggered in a watch window upon expanding the container instance. It's just one line of code, can you try it to help confirm it's likely to be the same issue?